# Specialize operator template via inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

To create a custom and lightweight adaption of Boost.Serialization I tried a few things so far. Let the following stub be given:

```
template<typename Archive>
class BasicStream {
public:
    template<typename Any>
    Archive& operator&(Any& data) {
        return Serialize(*this, data);
    }
};
```

In general almost all datatypes are handled correctly by the call to the global `Serialize` function, however there are some exceptions. For some datatypes I want to handle them differently based on the specified `Archive`. I tried to write

```
class OutputStream : public BasicStream<OutputStream> {
public:
    template<>
    OutputStream& operator&(MyExceptionalType& data) {
        // ... do something super special ... //
        return *this;
    }
};
```

however I get the error `IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with function template "OutputStream &BasicStream<Archive>::operator&(Any &data) [with Archive=OutputStream]"`. What is wrong with this attempt to inherit a general version of `operator&` but to specialize it in the derived classes?

Comment: What's wrong is that it's simply not allowed. Why not overload the free function `Serialize`?

Comment: @Xeo: It happens that I currently access a private `std::ofstream&` or `std::ifstream&` in my `OutputStream::operator&` or `InputStream::operator&` to read or write. Moreover I am using the `Serialize` function just for calls of the form `Archive & Any.Member;`.

Comment: The child class method is not a template method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
template<typename Archive>
class BasicStream {
public:
    template<typename Any>
    Archive& operator&(Any& data);
};

// generic implementation
template<typename Archive>
template<typename Any>
Archive& BasicStream<Archive>::operator&(Any& data) {
    return Serialize(*this, data);
}

class OutputStream : public BasicStream<OutputStream> {
};

// Specialize the original template, don't overwrite it
template<>
template<>
OutputStream& BasicStream<OutputStream>::operator&(MyExceptionalType& data) {
    // ... do something super special ... //
    return static_cast<OutputStream&>(*this);
}
```